# Can an epileptic seizure start in the spinal cord?

Tags: biochemistry, brain

My understanding of an epileptic seizure is caused by "invalid electrical signaling" in the brain. Can these start from the spinal cord  (outside the brain) and move into the brain and cause an epileptical seizure? (sorry for not using the right terms)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "outside the brain"?

Comment: can you provide example of place "outside the brain"? is it leg/spinal cord? Space 2 feet away? I am serious

Comment: Yes, spinal cord